# Javascript clearInterval on click

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I've written a small function that moves/bouces a button every 5 seconds like so:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="button">Text</a>
```

**JS:**

```
var interval;
function buttonShake(){ 
    var times = 5;
    var speed = 300;
    var distance = '15px';

    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        twitterButton.animate({
            left: '-='+distance
        }, speed).animate({
            left: '+='+distance
        }, speed);
    }
}
interval = setInterval(buttonShake, 4000);
```

What the button does it when clicked, it slides out a hidden box from the right hand side of the page. What I'm trying to do is prevent the button from bouncing once it has been clicked.

So I tried using the following

```
button.on('click', function(e){

    // do the slideout animation
    // add "open" class to the box

    if(box.hasClass('open')){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

});
```

The `button` and `box` elements have been defined correctly and the `open` class is appended to the box once it slides out, however clearing the interval doesn't appear to be working. It still continuously calls the `buttonShake()` function every 5 seconds.

Here is a JSFiddle with the full code for a live preview:

http://jsfiddle.net/30tsype8/3/

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript Console (F12) for errors?

Comment: @Katana314 - Yes, that was the first thing I did and there are no errors being shown

Comment: Is interval in scope when you call clearInterval?

Comment: You're not giving us the whole code, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong...

Comment: @Lodder could you duplicate this in a fiddle for us?

Comment: @HowardRenollet I've added a JSFiddle to the question

Comment: thanks, looking at it now :)

Comment: Ok, for me, the interval is clearing correctly, but the animation is still completing it's last cycle before the interval is cleared.  Is this the same behavior that you are experiencing, or is the interval never clearing for you?  (Chrome 38)

Comment: @HowardRenollet - The interval is simply never clearing. I just realised that I got the `setInterval` and `clearInterval` the wrong way round when checking for the `open` class, but this did not make any difference. I tried putting the `clearInterval` outside the class check and it now appears to be working. So it's something to do with the `hasClass` function which doesn't appear to be taken into consideration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that if you leave it for a while, the animation seems to go into overdrive and rather than running for around 3 secs and pausing for a second before starting again, it just constantly bounces. I think jQuery is overlapping its calls and getting confused and stuck in a loop.

As you want to stop bouncing the button when they expand the panel, I would immediately finish the animation after the panel has expanded using [`finish()`](http://api.jquery.com/finish/):

```
twitterWrapper.animate({
    right: right
}, function() {
    twitterButton.finish();
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30tsype8/4/)

Comment: Ahh nice one. I've never used `finish()` before. I did get it working in the end by using the `complete` callback on the animation and clearing/setting the interval in there, but your method is far cleaner. Much appreciated.